# Is it possible for the user (camera) to stick to a animated static-body entity?

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

Is it possible to "stick" the user (camera/cursor) to an animated static-body entity as it moves? 
For example, if I jump on to a static-bodied box which has an animation that moves it along the y-axis, how the user remain on that box? Similarly, if a box is animating its scale, when the camera is no longer "on" the box, why does it not fall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a moving platform, this is possible but a bit hacky. You'll need to attach a physics component to the camera, and neither `dynamic-body` nor `static-body` quite does the right thing. I've written a component in [aframe-extras](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras) to do it, called `kinematic-body`. Usage:

```
  <a-entity camera="userHeight: 1.6"
            universal-controls
            kinematic-body></a-entity>
```

Note that this only works with `universal-controls`, not the A-Frame default controls.

After that, you need the platform to not only move, but also update `el.body.position` and `el.body.velocity` on the entity, so that physics is properly synced. You can do this manually, or follow along with other examples in aframe-extras:

```
  <a-box id="platform1"
         width="4" height="0.25" depth="4"
         position="7 0.125 -15"
         velocity="0 0 0"
         toggle-velocity="axis: z; min: -5; max: 5;"
         static-body></a-box>
```

Working [demo](https://sandbox.donmccurdy.com/playground/) and [source code](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/blob/v3.13.1/examples/playground/index.html).

Scaling a `static-body` is harder. The physics engine has no concept of expanding that way, so you'd probably need to edit `el.body` manually, and this may or may not work.

There are other ways to do this without physics too, such as pointing a raycaster down from the camera and detecting the current platform that way.

Comment: This had the desired effect! I was using kinematic body, but not velocity/toggle-velocity. Thank you for this, as well as all the amazing a-frame extras. It's truly a fantastic contribution.